# wpf how to assign a grid to another grid

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to define a usercontrol first, inside it contain one grid(this grid contains one datagrid and some other controls).

Then in another window, i want to directly use that grid, is that possible?

Edit:
In that window, I don't want to only use that grid(cause I also want to show other stuff in that window), so I can't set its Content to that user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. make a user control and put that grid (with it's content) as child of the user control. Then anywhere you can use that user control.

To define the user control:

1. I create a new folder below the project in the solution. This folder's name is `UserInterface` (You can put other user controls and windows in this folder)
2. Right click on this folder and create a new user control (named `UserControl`) and put whatever you want in it. The default name space for this user control would be `[YourProjectName].UserInterface` (here my project's name is `WpfApplication`)
3. Now in the `MainWindow` (or any window that you are going to use this user control) add the proper name space like this:

   ```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.UserInterface">
    <Grid>
        <myNamespace:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl"/>
     </Grid>
   ```

Comment: how to use that user control in my window, e.g., set it to one grid of my window?

Comment: Define namespace: <Window xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.YourUserControl" ... And then Add UserControl to where you want in window: <uc:UserControlName x:Name="UserControlName/>. Just like this.

Comment: yes, thanks, i just found this way. I am a newer to stackoverflow, can you tell me how to close this question?

Comment: first I should delete my answer then I think you can delete your question. but before that you should not mark my answer as the correct answer (green check mark)

Comment: why delete them? i just want to close this question, so other people can know i already got the answer. Or in stackoverflow, it don't have option to close a question?

Comment: As far as you have set this answer as the correct one, It means that you have got the answer. No need to close it.

Comment: sorry, another question, now in another user control, i want to call that control again, i got exception from its InitializeComponent(). So is it possible for one user control to be used in more than one place?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a user control in any number of other windows or user controls. Like any other controls (`Button`, ...)